# Does gwan support SSI?

Tags: ssi, g-wan

Does gwan support SSI or there is another way to merge different HTML data ?

I'm not sure it's the best way, but I want to include static HTML data into another HTML files ... What do you use if SSI is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSI can be archived by G-WAN's Dynamic buffers API: simply replace a HTML comment with your partial HTML content.

Use xbuf_frfile() to load your HTML templates.
Use xbuf_repl() to "include" the partial HTML to your host page.

See contact.c from G-WAN samples.

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to load a servlet ... Using the /www folder and keep url user friendly like http://mydomain.com/my/wonderfull/page.html

Comment: G-WAN handlers are not supposed to modify the content. However, you can use a handler to rewrite the url.

Comment: Note: G-WAN **Connection handlers** are not supposed to modify contents, but G-WAN **Content handlers** have no other purpose.